# Use Subversion connector SVNKit 1.2.1 from trunk in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit

I want to test a feature coming with SVNKit 1.2.1, which is not yet available on the update sites of the Eclipse or the Polarion project.

I got a checkout as described under "Latest Development Version" on [svnkit.com/download.php](http://svnkit.com/download.php), successfully built it with ant and successfully installed it with the Eclipses software manager.

Now I don't see SVNKit 1.2.1 in the connector list in [Preferences / Team / SVN / SVN Connector].
So I cannot configure Eclipse to use SVNKit 1.2.1 as Subversion connector.

Anyone has an idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the concept wrong of how SVNKit is connected to Subversive. SVNKit itself being only the subversion library, it has to be available for the build of a Subversive trunk checkout.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer, Ansgar?  Your question exactly describes the trouble I'm having...